# Apache Camel FTP issue

Tags: apache-camel

I'm creating a tool that will keep on polling to read a specific CSV file called FEFO export.csv from a sequence of folders on an FTP server and will write to a sub folder on FTP called History, after processing this CSV file.

I searched a lot for solutions but none is working for me.

Here is my route I'm using and the error I'm getting.

```
from("timer:CSVReader?period=10s" )
                .log("Timer Triggered")
                .pollEnrich("ftp://username@host/ftp/erbranch/EDMS?password=xxxxx&useList=false&delete=true&fileName=FEFO export.csv")
                .to("log:?Level=INFO&showBody=true&showHeaders=true")
                .to("ftp://username@host/ftp/erbranch/EDMS/History/?password=xxxxxx");
```

ofcourse user name and host are different, here is the error I'm getting:

```
Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-bey-eliaskha-52853-1515749664372-0-1 on ExchangeId: ID-bey-eliaskha-52853-1515749664372-0-2). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: ftp://username@host/ftp/erbranch/EDMS?delete=true&fileName=FEFO+export.csv&password=xxxxxx&useList=false due to: No component found with scheme: ftp
```

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the exception message, it says

```
No component found with scheme: ftp
```

which means it cannot recognize ftp. You need to have camel-ftp dependency for this to work

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-ftp</artifactId>
        <version>X.X.X</version>
    </dependency>
```

Make sure you have the same version as camel-core

Comment: Great, I totally missed adding that in the POM.xml , I added it and ran the test, now I got another error, trying to get it sorted, any solution that you can advise?org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: File operation failed: null Connection is not open. Code: 221

Comment: make sure your server  where you are running has connectivity to that ftp server. and also have permissions to read and write from those directories

Comment: The username and password I'm using is with full access of reading and writing of the FTP server this is why I'm not sure what is happening, also I can connect and perform operations on the server with fileZilla ..

Comment: are you giving port information. And also as a first stop remove the last line in route where you are writing to some folder and see if it is able to read in the first place

Comment: No port information as I can connect without that, I read if there is no port info then it takes 21 as default, is this probably the issue? can I specify as no port?, since I'm connecting in filezilla without entering a port. I removed the writing to a folder and got the same issue.

Comment: FileZilla will use port 21 even if you don't specify one as this is the default port for FTP. If your password contains any characters that might get URL escaped (e.g. % or =) then enclose the password with RAW: `?password=RAW(xxxxxxxx)` and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Yes, the port was the issue although it is taking 21 as default, I had to add it to the URL to work smooth. But I faced another issue as below, although I'm using correct username and password in the FTP route but still getting the error, I'm using the same username/pword as what I'm doing in FileZilla ERROR CamelLogger.java 204 | Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-bey-eliaskha-49444-1516003450660-0-3 on ExchangeId: ID-bey-eliaskha-49444-1516003450660-0-2). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: GenericFileOperationFailedException: File operation failed: 530 User cannot log in.